# Replace spaces or -'s with _'s if line starts with a digit

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have a text file as follows:

```
#1xx Informational responses
100=Continue
101=Switching Protocols
102=Processing
#2xx Success
200=OK
201=Created
202=Accepted
203=Non-Authoritative Information
204=No Content
205=Reset Content
206=Partial Content
207=Multi-Status
208=Already Reported
226=IM Used
```

What I want to do is to convert this into the one below:

```
#1xx_Informational responses
100=Continue
101=Switching_Protocols
102=Processing
#2xx_Success
200=OK
201=Created
202=Accepted
203=Non_Authoritative_Information
204=No_Content
205=Reset_Content
206=Partial_Content
207=Multi_Status
208=Already_Reported
226=IM_Used
```

I could use:

```
:%s/[ \|-]/_/g
```

but it unconditionally changes spaces or -'s with _'s in all lines, including the very first line as:

```
#1xx_Informational_responses
```

I do not want that. Instead, what I want to achieve is to replace spaces and -'s with _'s only if a line starts with a digit. For all other lines, I do not want to perform replace operation.

Is there any way to "conditionally" perform replace operation? I do not want to deal with line numbers, line numbers may change. I want answers with regarding the content of the line (starting with a digit for this case), not line number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `:%s/\(^[0-9].*\)\@<=[ -]/_/g`

Comment: interesting. thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, sorry, but i think that doesn't work, as the first group will not match again, as with the `g` will don't work.

Comment: @LuisColorado There is no "group" here. `\(...\)\@<=` is a *lookbehind* equivalent in Vim.

Comment: Well, not fluent about that _lookbehind_ thing,  sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:g/^\d/s/[ -]/_/g
```

The `:global` command executes a command on each line matched by a given regex.

(By the way, your regex `[ \|-]` matches a character that is either a space or `\` or `|` or `-`.)

Comment: Awesome.! Thank you.! (stackover flow does not allow me to accept your answer at the moment. I will do so in 8 mins). Thanks again. :]

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it through sed, which allows to select the lines to operate on

```
:%!sed '/^[0-9]/s/-/_/g'
```

this line selects all lines beginning in digit, on then, it substitutes all (as from option `g`) `-` chars with `_`.